# Frankenserve... how to stop polyserve?

Tags: polymer, polymer-starter-kit

While at the (excellent!) Polymer Summit in London, as part of the codelabs I ran "polymer serve" and got the application template up and running: http://localhost:8080/
Great! But how do I stop the server? It's continually running and survives a reboot. I need to get on with another project :P

I'm on Windows (W10 64). I have tried the usual method I have used before to stop node servers (is Polyserve node based?).
If i run netstat -an there is nothing listed related to 8080
If I run 
        netstat -ano | find "LISTENING" | find "8080"
nothing is returned.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, I guess this is just down to the hard caching by the service worker, as a hard reload refreshes as expected.
Lots of potential for confusion with service worker lifecycle!

Edit: "unregister service worker" in devtools did the trick!